# give the Airflow account Data Viewer permissions on the config_prd dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

There is a project in bigquery called project1 and it has a dataset called config_prd. I am trying to create a table in the dataset if it does not exist and then update the table each time I trigger the pipeline. Creating and updating tables are airflow tasks.
At the moment the DAG fails because

```
Access Denied: Table project1:config_prd.table1: User does not have bigquery.tables.get 
permission for table project1:config_prd.table1.
```

**My Question:**
So the airflow service account needs that permission to check if the table exists. How I can give the airflow account data viewer permission to config_prd dataset?

My suggested solution:
go to the GCP consol > API and Services > credentials > under the service account section I can see an email address:

> airflow@project1.iam.gserviceaccount.com

I have to copy this email address and go to the GCP console > IAM and Admin >IAM > add
member > enter the email address and role is viewer

Please let me know if this is correct.
My other question is we have several projects on GCP. Should I do this for every single project?
another question: how previously airflow was able to update other tables in the dataset?

Comment: You can grant your service account access to specific BigQuery datasets as per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#controlling_access_to_a_dataset ..
Let me know if this helps

Comment: As for your last 2 questions, they could not be answered here, and I would recommend for you to either get support from GCP support https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-support